# SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two classes each one from Data/Business layer, I have used SQL Sever more than MySQL, so what I want it's to know if MySQL can handle the same syntax of SQL Server or an approach to it. This is what I commonly use in SQL Server for stored procedures:

```
//This goes on Data Layer
public int InsertValuesWithSP(string storedProcedure, SqlParameter spParameter)
{
    try
    {
       int result = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn.Connect(),CommandType.StoredProcedure, storedProcedure, spParameter)
       return result;
    }
    catch
    {
       return -1;
    }
}
```

After that I go over my business layer for the `SqlParameters`

```
//This goes on Business Layer 
public int Values(int id, string name )
{
     SqlParameter[] pa = new SqlParameter[2];
     pa[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID",id);
     pa[1] = new SqlParameter("@Name",name);
     //SP called "Insert_Values" it inserts id && name 
     int res = transaction.InsertValueswithSP("Insert_Values",pa);
     return res;          
 }
```

But in my try to do the same with MySQL I have done this:

```
public int Transaction(string sp,MySqlParameter[] mysqlparameter)
{
     try
     {
        int a = MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn.Connect(),query, mysqlparameter);

        return a;
      }
      catch
      {
        return -1;
      }
 }
```

Note: I know that there's no `CommandType` like SQL Server so I have try:

```
int a = MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn.Connect(),"Call " + query, mysqlparameter);
```

So for me this was a good idea because it work for one of my methods but I realize that it didn't work for this one.

```
public void RegisterUser(string fname,string mname)
        {
            MySqlParameter[] par = new MySqlParameter[2];
            par[0] = new MySqlParameter("FN", fname);
            par[1] = new MySqlParameter("MN", mname);

            tr.Transaction("Register_Employee",par);
        }
```

Until this is what I did, seems really similar but at the moment of the execution, 
the stored procedure doesn't work, I don't know what to do I already tried to put `@` to my parameters and the only thing that I keep getting is :

> The MySqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null MySqlParameter type objects.

Comment: If you used the abstract classes like DbCommand, DbParameter etc you wouldn't need to change the code at all. BTW what are the `SqlHelper`, `MySqlHelper` classes? They aren't part of .NET. What do you mean that `CommandType` isn't available? It's part of ADO.NET, not of a specific provider.

Comment: I mean I know  that commandtype is from ado.net but what I make reference is that sqlhelper has 9 overloads, one in specific is the first that iI show you in my code but mysql does not have that overload attributes so i want to see how works on mysql.

Comment: There are no such things as SqlHelper or MySqlHelper in ADO.NET. It's impossible to answer a question about an arbitrary class. Is it your own code or part of a third-party tool? If it's your own, just add the overloads you want. If it's a third party tool, contact its author. At least post what these classes are and where they come from

Comment: They are from mysql.data.dll and microsoft.applicationblocks.data.dll but its fine I already found the solution thanks.